# Icon no es compatible con String

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo este código y quiero utilizar `getLblFoto()` para guardar una foto que el usuario escoge pero cada vez que lo voy a guardar o cada vez que lo codifico me dice getIcon no es compatible con String que es el tipo de datos de la varible.

```
public void guardar()
{
  VentanaAgr_Contacto1 vn= new VentanaAgr_Contacto1();
  arreglo.add(new Controlador.Contacto(vn.getLblFoto().getIcon(),
                  vn.getTxt_Nombre().getText(),
                  vn.getTxt_Apellido().getText(),
                  vn.getTxt_Movil().getText(),
                  vn.getTxt_Casa().getText(),
                  vn.getTxt_Personal().getText(),
                  vn.getTxt_Trabajo().getText(),
                  vn.getTxtPanel_Direccion().getText()));
    }
```

El código donde cargo la imagen es este:

```
public void Cargar_Imagen() {
        File fichero;
        int resultado;
        VentanaImg_Contacto vi= new VentanaImg_Contacto();

        FileNameExtensionFilter filtro=
                new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG y PNG", "jpg", "png");

        vi.getJchCargarFoto().setFileFilter(filtro);
        resultado= vi.getJchCargarFoto().showOpenDialog(null);

        if(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION== resultado)
        {
            fichero= vi.getJchCargarFoto().getSelectedFile();
            try {
                ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(fichero.toString());
                Icon icono= new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().
                        getScaledInstance(VentanaAgr_Contacto1.lblFoto.getWidth(),
                                VentanaAgr_Contacto1.lblFoto.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                VentanaAgr_Contacto1.lblFoto.setIcon(icono);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al abrir la imagen "+e);
            }
        }else if(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION == null ? Integer.toString(resultado) == null : JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION.equals(Integer.toString(resultado)))
            {
                vi.getJchCargarFoto().setVisible(false);
            }
    }
```

Esto me presenta la imagen en el `JLabel` pero no me guardad la imagen

Comment: David cual es el String con el que intentas crear el archivo?

Comment: En otra clase tengo el String definido, de ahí este código `new Controlador.Contacto` en esa clase Contacto tengo una variable privada llamada **String imagen**, el problema realmente está en que no puedo ver la imagen cuando intento abrir otra ventana que recupera los datos, posiblemente tenga que utilizar **getIcon** para eso en el método **guardar** de arriba pero me da error diciéndome que Icon no puede ser convertido a String o **Icon cannot be converted to String**. Agradezco mucho tu ayuda de antemano.

Comment: cambia `String imagen` por `Icon imagen`....

Answer (score -2):

Tu método `Controlador.Contacto()` esta preparado para recibir un `String` como primer parámetro, tu estas enviando un `Icon`:

```
vn.getLblFoto().getIcon()
```

cambia a :

```
vn.getLblFoto().getText()
```

para obtener el texto del `JLabel`.

Comment: No obtengo nada, el Label queda vacío